# Error when mocking NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to mock NSManagedObjectContext so that when executeFetchRequest is called it returns a mock User.

```
class MockNSManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {

        override func executeFetchRequest(request: NSFetchRequest) throws -> [AnyObject] {
        let mockUser: User = User()
        mockUser.usDisplayName = "Mock User"
        mockUser.usUserID = "MockUserId"

        return [mockUser]
    }
}
```

I'm unit testing a method on a data manager class like this

```
func test_When_getUserByEmail_Is_Called_It_Returns_A_User_If_Found() {

    let mockManagedObjectContext = MockNSManagedObjectContext()
    let arUserDataHelper = ARUserDataHelper(managedObjectContext: mockManagedObjectContext)
    let returnValue = arUserDataHelper.getUserByEmail("MockUserId")

    XCTAssert(returnValue != nil)

}
```

**EDIT: added ARUserDataHelper class**

```
class ARUserDataHelper {

   let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext

   init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext){
    self.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
   }

   func getUserByEmail(email: String) -> User? {
       let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
       fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usUserID == %@", email)
       if let fetchResults = try! self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [User] {
          return fetchResults.count > 0 ? fetchResults[0] : nil
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

When I run the test I get the error

> failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[ARRO.User
>   setUsDisplayName:]: 
>       unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2c2dbfc50"

when setting the property on the User in executeFetchRequest

```
mockUser.usDisplayName = "Mock User"
```

I have a .NET background and learning iOS development at the moment so not really sure where to go from here.

Any ideas?

Comment: I gave up trying to make unit testing work with Core Data and later I have regretted for even deciding to use Core Data. I would suggest you to keep your entities slim as possible and have some wrapper for them to perform computational intensive tasks and unit test these wrappers.

Comment: Please provide related code in `ARUserDataHelper`.

Comment: Is your `User` inherit from `NSManagedObject`? If so, it seems that you try to use dynamic properties.

Comment: @hris.to code added.

Comment: @R.K. Yes it does. Not sure what you mean so I will google but the code that sets the property is the same as if I was using real CoreData so don't know why that would make a difference. Can you explain further please?

Comment: All properties of NSManagedObject successor are dynamic. This means that they haven't methods realization. So for NSManagedObject CoreData framework does all magic to create this methods at runtime. If you want to use this object as mock you should try do same thing.